# Ada 2012 - replace Fixed_Decimal_Type'Round() with customised version?

Tags: rounding, ada, fixed-point

Recently I have had joyous success when providing my own replacement `'Write ()` procedure for a custom record type, such as...

```
   type Pixel_Format is
      record
         --  blah blah
      end record;

   procedure Pixel_Format_Write (
     Stream : not null access Root_Stream_Type'Class;
     Item : in Pixel_Format);

   for Pixel_Format'Write use Pixel_Format_Write;
```

I was using this to convert certain record members from little-endian to big-endian when writing to a network stream.  Worked beautifully.

By the same thinking I wondered if it is possible to replace the `'Round ()` function of decimal fixed point types, so I attempted a quick and dirty test...

```
   --  This is a "Decimal Fixed Point" type
   type Money_Dec_Type is delta 0.001 digits 14;

   --  ...

   function Money_CustomRound(X : in Money_Dec_Type)
     return Money_Dec_Type'Base;

   for Money_Dec_Type'Round use Money_CustomRound; -- COMPILER COMPLAINS HERE

   --  ...

   function Money_CustomRound(X : in Money_Dec_Type)
     return Money_Dec_Type'Base is

     begin
        return 0.001;
   end Money_CustomRound;
```

Alas, GNAT finds this offensive:

`attribute "Round" cannot be set with definition clause`

**Question:**

Am I attempting the impossible?  Or is there a way to change the default `'Round` attribute, in the same way that changing `'Write` is possible?

**Context to the question:**

I have a set of about 15 different ways of rounding currency values that change from one project to the next (sometimes within the same project!).  Examples include:

- Round halves away from zero (Ada's default it seems)
- Round halves towards zero
- Statistical (a re-entrant type that requires global housekeeping)
- Round towards evens OR odds
- Rounds towards +INF / -INF
- ...

It would be a powerful tool to be able to have this kind of functionality become transparent to the programmer by using certain rounding methods defined at the generic package level.

The angel on my other shoulder suggests I'm asking for something completely insane.

I wonder this because the documentation (ALRM and "Barnes 2012") both give a function specification for the default procedure.  Why would they do that if one couldn't replace it with another of one's own design?

Comment: You’d have to write the code anyway, so what benefit would you get redefining the attribute rather than just having a function `Round`? ... which would in fact end up with shorter code

Comment: @SimonWright, existing functions that use the old default behaviour would not have to be modified for the new requirements.

Comment: I encounter a lot this « fear » of find-replace code when doing port/refacto. I often consider it as a symbol of lack of confidence of the management level into developers and software evolutions. Even I you could redefine le ‘Round, you would have to assess (test) it’s impact on all its users. Impact analysis and tests will occur anyways. Why then making « open + edit » n files a feared event ? A software changes over time, no matter how hard people wish it not to.

Comment: @LoneWanderer, yes you're right.  I wish it wasn't such a sticking point too.  I also wish I had any power to do anything about it :)

Comment: @LoneWanderer it's not always fear, there's also a simple convenience factor. If it "just happens" then you aren't doing extra work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot redefine the `Round` attribute. Attributes can only be queried (see [RM K.2](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-K-2.html)). Only aspects can be (re)defined using an aspect specification (see [RM K.1](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-K-1.html); some exceptions apply). The RM gives specifications of the functions behind the attributes to clarify the signatures to the reader.

Comment: Four attributes: Read/Write and Input/output can actually be redefined. These are the only exceptions however.